# Is using `@Lazy` on a component constructor equal to annotating every argument?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

In Spring, consider a `@Service` class, that has the following autowired constructor:

```
public DogService(@Lazy CatService catService, @Lazy MouseService mouseService) {
  this.catService = catService;
  this.mouseService = mouseService;
}
```

is this equivalent to?

```
@Lazy
public DogService(CatService catService, MouseService mouseService) {
  this.catService = catService;
  this.mouseService = mouseService;
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, this is equivalent.

The [`@Lazy` javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Lazy.html) states :

> In addition to its role for component initialization, this annotation
> may also be placed on injection points marked with
> `org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired` or
> `javax.inject.Inject`: In that context, it leads to the creation of a
> lazy-resolution proxy for all affected dependencies, as an alternative
> to `using org.springframework.beans.factory.ObjectFactory` or
> `javax.inject.Provider`.

The important part is :

> **it leads to the creation of a lazy-resolution proxy for all affected
> dependencies**

in terms of dependencies your `DogService` bean has two of them autowired in any case : `CatService catService` and `MouseService mouseService`.
So annotating the constructor or all parameters individually will produce the same result : the two dependencies will be lazy loaded.

**Note**: I have tested them and the behavior is exactly the same in both cases.