# Using @Lazy with @RequiredArgsConstructor

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, lombok, lazy-initialization

```
...
@RequiredArgsContructor(onConstructor_ = {@Lazy})
Class A{
  private final B b;
  @Lazy
  private final C c;
}
```

```
Class A{
  private final B b;
  private final C c;
  A(B b,@Lazy C c){
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
  }
}
```

Is it the same?

I want to use `@Lazy` with `@RequiredArgsConstructor`.

Answer (score 2):

It's not the same. When you put `@Lazy` over constructor it leads to the creation of a lazy-resolution proxy for all affected dependencies, i.e. in your first case both `b` and `c` injected into constructor are resolved lazily.

In the second case only `c` is resolved lazily.

See [Is using `@Lazy` on a component constructor equal to annotating every argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49433935/is-using-lazy-on-a-component-constructor-equal-to-annotating-every-argument)

> I want to using @Lazy with @RequiredArgsConstructor

Use your first approach.

P.S. Btw, having `@Lazy` over constructor in the first case makes redundant `@Lazy` over `private final C c;`.

Answer (score 1):

As @Sergey said, it's not the same, it affects all dependencies.

Referring to [Mafor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59510923/10231374):

> You can configure Lombok to copy the `@Lazy` annotation from the field
> to the constructor's parameter.

Create `lombok.config` file in the project's root and add the following line:

```
lombok.copyableAnnotations += org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy
```

Then you can define your class as follows:

```java
@RequiredArgsContructor
Class A{
  private final B b;
  @Lazy
  private final C c;
}
```